# Behaviours and Triggers

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a simple login form with two fields username and pass. Using behaviours I implemented email validation (not empty, valid email) and pass validation (not empty)

```
             <StackLayout Padding="30" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Spacing="15">
                    <Entry Text="{Binding Email}" Keyboard="Email" IsEnabled="{Binding IsNotBusy}" Placeholder="Email address">
                        <Entry.Behaviors>
                            <local:EntryValidatorBehavior IsCheckEmail="true" ValidateFromStart="false" IsCheckEmpty="true" x:Name="emailValidator" />
                        </Entry.Behaviors>
                    </Entry>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference emailValidator}, Path=Message}" />
                    <Entry Text="{Binding Password}" IsPassword="true" IsEnabled="{Binding IsNotBusy}" Placeholder="Password">
                        <Entry.Behaviors>
                            <local:EntryValidatorBehavior ValidateFromStart="false" IsCheckEmpty="true" x:Name="passwordValidator">
                            </local:EntryValidatorBehavior>
                        </Entry.Behaviors>
                    </Entry>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference passwordValidator}, Path=Message}" />
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Text="Forgot Password?" Command="{Binding ForgotButton}" TextColor="White" HeightRequest="40" VerticalOptions="End">
                        </Button>
                        <Button HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Text="Sign In" Command="{Binding LoginButton}" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#f50057" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="100">
                        </Button>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
```

This works perfectly, but at the bottom of the form I have a Login button which should be hidden as long as both email and password are not valid.

How can this be implemented? I was thinking by using Triggers

```
<Button HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Text="Sign In" Command="{Binding LoginButton}" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#f50057" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="100" IsVisible="false">
                        <Button.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Button">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <MultiTrigger TargetType="Button">
                                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference emailValidator}, Path=IsValid}" Value="True" />
                                            <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference passwordValidator}, Path=Text.IsValid}" Value="True" />
                                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True" />
                                    </MultiTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Button.Style>
                    </Button>
```

but this doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is Path=IsValid and Path=Text.IsValid supposed to be different?

Comment: Thanks mate, that is! I spent 2 hours trying to figure what is wrong here.

Comment: Don't forget to give thumps up. And Correct the question so that others can look at it.